# Using RStudio image dimensions with ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have previously used RStudio's Export --> Save as image --> Width/Height utility with great success. However, I would like to automate the workflow and save the image as part of my `ggplot` command. Currently, I use:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
ggsave('test.png', width=100, height=100, units='mm')
```

If in the utility window I have set Height=100 and Width=100, how do I translate this to `ggsave` or something similar?

Comment: In your example it looks like you are omitting a `)` at the end, although a 100x100 mm^2 plot is incredibly small

Comment: @DaveGruenewald - sorry, typo. this is just an example.

Comment: @r2evans - it still works on the chain, and is easier to do as one command

Comment: Learn something new everyday, sorry 'bout that :-)